# Set plink username per-host from git?

Tags: git, ssh, config, plink

I have the following Git configuration file (I'm using plink because this host is configured with a TPMVSC-backed SSH key):

```ini
# This is Git's per-user configuration file.
[user]
    name = James Edington
    email = james.edington@example.com

[core]
    sshCommand = plink -batch

[ssh]
    variant = plink

[credential "ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"]
    username = ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
```

However, Git doesn't actually seem to be passing this username to plink.

There are a few **workarounds** I've found, such as:

- Baking my username into the repository URL: `git clone ssh://ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST@git-codecommit…`
- Baking my username into the SSH command: `(export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="plink -batch -l ABCDEFG…"; git clone ssh://git-codecommit.us…/project && cd project && git config --local core.sshCommand "$GIT_SSH_COMMAND")`

But I'm wondering what the **proper solution** is.

I *have* tried setting [`ssh.variant`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-sshvariant) to `plink`, `auto`, and `ssh`; none of these works. Passing `GIT_TRACE=1` reveals that Git *isn't* passing a username parameter on the command-line to plink in any case.

I have *also* tried adding an appropriate [entry](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ssh_config(5)) to `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config`, but plink does not seem to load this file.

It *seems* like Git's not picking up the per-host credential directive, but according to [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials#_credential_contexts), I think it should match as I've written it:

> both protocols are the same, both hosts are the same, and the "pattern" URL does not care about the path component at all.

---

Is Git truly bugged not to actually *support* per-host usernames with plink at this time? Or am I doing something wrong?

Question asked in the context of Git 2.38.1.windows.1; PuTTY-CAC Plink Release 0.77; Windows 10.0.19044; Amazon CodeCommit server.

Comment: https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.40.0/connect.c#L1288 -- the function doesn't even _look at_ the username, unfortunately. (Presumably this is because Git assumes your SSH client will handle username lookups from `~/.ssh/config` or similar, neglecting the fact that some SSH variants don't have this capability.)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can transfer nothing from Git to Plink
2. You have to define connection-credential for plink in two (at least) ways

- Putty session
- user in plink options

Both variants **will require** changing `core.sshCommand` also

Comment: You're saying that the current version of Git **simply doesn't support** `credential.ssh://*.username`?

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude: not, but "only with some core.sshCommand". No, it's not documented AFAICK, but Win-environment is always a "poor kinsman" for Git